# How to split string separated with comma. PHP

Tags: php, ionic-framework

Hello i want to split my string that i have in my mysql field so i show each value of the string.

This is how it inserted in the mysql table. The field's name is tags.

the string inserted like this on db. **movies,songs,poems**

this is what i have so far.

```js
allMediaSet() {
    this
        .userData
        .allMediasGuest()
        .pipe(
            map((data: any) => {
                if (data.success) {
                    this.allMedia = data.mediaFeedGuest;
                    this.mediaVideo = this.allMedia.filter(
                        res => res.type === 'V'
                    );
                    this.mediaAudio = this.allMedia.filter(
                        res => res.type === 'A'
                    );
                    this.mediaPhotos = this.allMedia.filter(
                        res => res.type === 'P'
                    );
                    this.mediaTexts = this.allMedia.filter(
                        res => res.type === 'T'
                    );

                    **if (this.allMedia.tags !== null) {
                        this.tags = this.allMedia.tags.split(',');
                        console.log('ddd');
                        console.log(this.tags);
                    }            
                }
            }
        )
    ).subscribe()
}
```

and on html

```html
<ul *ngFor="let item of tags; let index = index">
   <li>
      <a>{{item}}</a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

i want to show tags only if there are there on the field thats why the if statement and then split by comma.

php function

```
 function allMediaGuest()
 {

$request = \Slim\Slim::getInstance()->request();
$data = json_decode($request->getBody());
$response['success'] = true;

$db = getDB();

$sql = "SELECT M.msg_id, M.uid_fk, M.message, M.created, M.comment_count, M.share_count,U.uid, U.username,U.profile_pic,U.bio,
U.artisticBehaviour,M.type, M.title, M.description, M.media_pic, M.point_count, P.image_path, M.allow_editable, M.status,M.tags, M.views_count, M.created 
FROM users U 
LEFT JOIN messages M ON M.uid_fk = U.uid 
LEFT JOIN user_uploads P ON M.msg_id = P.msg_id_fk WHERE M.status='1' ORDER BY M.msg_id DESC ";
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
$mediaFeedGuest = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

foreach ($mediaFeedGuest as $feed) {
    $feed->media_pic = SITE_URL . 'mediaPic/' . $feed->media_pic;
    $feed->profile_pic = SITE_URL . 'usersPic/' . $feed->profile_pic;
    $feed->image_path = SITE_URL . $feed->image_path;
    $feed->media_type = $feed->media_type;
   // $feed->status = $feed == 1;
}

$data['success'] = true;
$data['mediaFeedGuest'] = $mediaFeedGuest;
echo json_encode($data);
}
```

I am getting nothing on console not ddd nor tags when i put this.allMedia.tags before if statement returns undefined [photo of field in table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1K1p2.png)

Comment: use `explode()` function.

Comment: `split my string that i have in my mysql field so i show each value of the string`...storing multiple values in a single database field like this is a fundamental design flaw in your schema which is likely to cause you all sorts of headaches. Please learn about database normalisation, table relationships and foreign keys.

Comment: Please provide the PHP code too, as you have tagged php.

Comment: Could you run this `console.log(this.allMedia.tags)` before the `if` statement inside your `allMediaSet` function, and update your question with the output of the `console.log` I mentioned in my comment?

Comment: console.log(this.allMedia.tags);  before if returns undefined

Comment: i have updates to show you php function thanks

Comment: explode like this? $singleTag = explode(',', $mediaFeedGuest->tags);

Comment: If `this.allMedia.tags` is `undefined` then, this is the reason the if statement body not executed.

You have to find out why the `this.allMedia.tags` is undefined first, and then proceed with the if statement body debugging.

Comment: i don't know why it gets undefined. if i run this it works.  <ul *ngFor="let item of allMedia; let index = index">
       <li><a >{{item.tags}}</a></li>
      </ul>